# Force triangles to have same size despite different content

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, polygon

I have the following code that makes 4 triangles:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{triangle} = [regular polygon,
regular polygon sides=3,draw, text width=0.5em,
inner sep=0.3mm, outer sep=0mm, shape border rotate=-90]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[triangle] (t1) {$A$};
\node[triangle,below=1cm of t1] (t2) {};
\node[triangle,below=1cm of t2] (t3) {$q$};
\node[triangle,below=1cm of t3] (t4) {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want all four triangles to have the same size, and it should be the size of the second triangle (the smallest one) from the code.

The auto-sizing  should basically ignore the content. It should also shift the content slightly to the left, where the triangle is larger. Then for example the \frac{1}{2} should still be able to fit into the small triangle.

How can I make this work? I already tried to set inner sep=0, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `tkz-euclide` package.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{%
pics/triangle/.style args={#1}{
    code={
    \def\edge{1}% edge of triangle
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](90:\edge){B}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](30:\edge){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{G}
\node at (G) {$#1$};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t/\y in {A/1,/2, q/3,\frac{1}{2}/4}{
\pic at (0,-\y*1.2) {triangle=\t};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you like this simple way? instead using `node`, creat a pic to avoid inner sep; the content are added via separate node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{1}
\tikzset{triangle/.pic={
\draw (0:\r)--(120:\r)--(-120:\r)--cycle;
}}
\path 
(0,0) pic{triangle} node{$A$}
(3,0) pic{triangle} 
(6,0) pic{triangle} node{$q$}
(9,0) pic{triangle} node{$\dfrac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```